# Creating SubscriberList object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, unsubscribe

I am trying to create custom unsubscribe for publication lists. I want to dynamically pull in the list id which is being passed through parameters. I know the id is being stored because it's showing when I output it. when I use 
`@listid` vs the actual id like `1234` my cloud page won't publish. Can I not use a variable for the id? would I just have to make an if-else block?

It seems to be able to use a variable when creating the client object and I use `@ClientID`.

I am pretty sure it is something in the block where I am creating the SubscriberList object because removing it all together allows the page to publish as well.

```
SET @jid = RequestParameter("jobid")
SET @listid = RequestParameter("listid")
SET @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("SubscriberKey")
SET @EmailAddress = RequestParameter("email_address")
SET @ClientID = "7326442"


SET @ll_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress) 
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey) 

SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @ClientID)
SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "Client", @client)

SET @List = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@List, "ID", @listid)
SetObjectProperty(@List, "Status", "Unsubscribed")
AddObjectArrayItem(@ll_sub, "Lists", @List)

Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","Status")
AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save) 
Set @update_sub = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub,@update_sub_status,@update_sub_errorcode, @options)
```

Comment: So i changed 'ID' to 'objectID' and it now accepts my variable ID and unsubs from the correct list. Will this method give me any problems that im not seeing currently?
`SetObjectProperty(@List, "ID", @listid)
SetObjectProperty(@List, "ObjectID", @listid)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to include the *specified* properties -- *IDSpecified* and *StatusSpecified*:

```
SET @List = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@List, "ID", @listid)
SetObjectProperty(@List, "IDSpecified", "true" )
SetObjectProperty(@List, "Status", "Unsubscribed")
SetObjectProperty(@List, "StatusSpecified", "true" )
AddObjectArrayItem(@ll_sub, "Lists", @List)
```

Reference: [**Add Subscribers to a List**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_subscribers_to_a_list.htm)